# Character is moving in weird ways when using Transform.forward in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I've looked all around Google and have yet to find something to fix this problem. I am using this extremely simple code in a 3D game I am creating in the Unity Game Engine 5.0. It isn't working out too well, it is hard to explain the thing that happens, so here are a series of pictures that should explain what I am experiencing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHSZP.jpg

Obviously I noticed the trend in that every 90 degrees my camera turns, my character wants to move 180 degrees, but I can't find any solution to this, any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code that I use to move my character, I also want to implement some strafing in the future, so please take that into consideration when replying, thanks!

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {   
        transform.Translate(transform.forward *  moveSpeed);
    }

}
```

If you require any extra information, please just ask.

Cheers,
Cold999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me...

All I had to do was multiply the rotation of the camera by 2 so that it would follow up with the player.

Comment: Why are you translating the _character_ as a _function of the rotation of the camera?_.  A character has its own rotation so if done correctly `transform.Translate(transform.forward *  moveSpeed);` with respect to the character's `Update()` should have worked I would have thought.

Comment: That is actually in the `FixedUpdate()` of my _PlayerController_ class. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: No worries.  Main thing is that you got it going :)